# How can I query the subscribed webhook events for a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I would like to be able to query the webhook configuration of a Facebook app.

That is, when you setup a webhook for your FB app, you specify what events you want to subscribe to:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#setup

My question is pretty simple: is there a way to query which events have been subscribed to for a given FB app/page ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do this by querying "subscriptions" of the Graph API.

E.g.

1. Go to Graph API explorer tool on developers.facebook.com
2. In the "Access Token:" field, enter the string: `YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET`
3. In the GET/v2.8/ field, enter: `YOUR_APP_ID/subscriptions`

The resulting JSON will contain what events you've registered for: `data[0].fields`

A smart friend told me how to do this. :)